# Determine ratio of images while using .map() after they load in react

Tags: reactjs

I am using .map() to return some image sources from an API call to and img tag. What I would like to do is get the ratio or dimensions of each image and set a classname to the containing div of each one. The issue I am running into is that I am trying to use the useState hook to set the ration but obviously it is just setting the ration of one of the images. I know that it needs some rework on when the ratio gets set and probably don't need to use useState. Any help is appreciated. Here is what I have tried so far.

```
export const imageCard = ({items}) => {
const [ratio, setRatio] = useState();

const onImgLoad = (url) => { 
    if (url !== null) { 
       let img = new Image(); 
       img.src = url; 
       setRatio(img.width / img.height); 
       console.log(ratio); 
    } 
 };

return(

{items &&
       items.map((item, i) => (
              <div className={ratio > 1.75 ? 'card-item wide' : 'card-item'} key={i}>
                   {item.mainImage && (
                      <LazyLoadImage
                        alt={item.title}
                        effect="blur"
                        src={item.mainImage}
                        afterLoad={() => {
                          onImgLoad(item.mainImage);
                        }}
                      />
                    )}
             </div>
       )
   )}
 )
})
```

Comment: Your `onImgLoad` function won't work: the `img.width` property of a `new Image` (aka `HTMLImageElement`) will be 0 or undefined because the image set by `src` is loaded asynchronously. Instead you should only use the `naturalWidth` property (not `width`) **after** the `HTMLImageElement`'s `load` event has fired).

Comment: Thanks for the response! So basically update the onImgLoad function to use the naturalWidth and naturalHeight properties instead and do you mean adding img.onLoad to the onImgLoad function?

Comment: I have updated the onImgLoad function to match what was suggested. It does get each individual image ratio. However, the containing div's class just takes the first ratio. Do you have any suggestions on how to get that to apply to each item in the array?